# Source has X element(s) but target allows only 1

Tags: angular, typescript

The typescript compile show this error:

> Source has X element(s) but target allows only 1.

```
export const FooMapping: [{id: FooOperation, display: string}] = [
    { id: FooOperation.Undefined, display: 'Nothing' },
    { id: FooOperation.A, display: 'I'm A' },
    { id: FooOperation.B, display: 'I'm B' }
];

export enum FooOperation {
    Undefined = 0,
    A = 1,
    B = 2,
}
```

What is the correct way to define an array of special object of `{id: FooOperation, display: string}`?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

`[{id: FooOperation, display: string}]` defines a [tuple](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#tuple) of exactly one element.

Try:

```
export const FooMapping: Array<{id: FooOperation; display: string}> = [
    { id: FooOperation.Undefined, display: 'Nothing' },
    { id: FooOperation.A, display: "I'm A" },
    { id: FooOperation.B, display: "I'm B" }
];
```

Or think about something like:

```
interface Foo {
  id: FooOperation;
  display: string;
}

export const FooMapping: Foo[] = [...];
```

Answer (score 76):

I had the same problem. The braces have to go after the type:

```
const FooMapping: [{id: FooOperation, display: string}]
```

should be

```
const FooMapping: {id: FooOperation, display: string}[]
```

Easy way to remember this is to replace the object with a type and see if it makes sense:

`[string]` doesn't work but `string[]` does

Comment: Literally facepalmed over this one. Thanks for this answer.

Comment: This was my problem, but more specifically I wanted an array of arrays of a type, wasn't sure of the syntax so I guessed `[Item[]]`, got OP's error. Changing it to `item[][]` fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

```
const sendArr
    : [{
      entity: string | number | undefined,
      identifier: Array<string | Types.ObjectId | undefined>//[Types.ObjectId | string | undefined]
    }] = [{
      entity: '',
      identifier: [undefined]
    }]
```