# Source has 2 element(s) but target allows only 1. Typescript spread operator

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to spread all values in array and append a new object in my reducer.

my **state interface**:

```
export interface IBasketState {
products: [
    {
        id: number | undefined;
        name: string;
        smallQ: number; //small packages quantity
        smallTotalP: number; //price for all small packages
        largeQ: number; //large packages quantity
        largeTotalP: number; //price for all large packages
        orderPrice: number; //total price of this order
    }
  ];
    totalPrice: number;
}
```

**Reducer** add item function:

```
const BasketReducer = (basketState: IBasketState, action: IBasketAction): IBasketState => {
//ADD ITEM
if (action.type === "Add item") {
    const { id, name, smallQ, smallP, largeQ, price } = action.payload;
    let smallTotalPrice = smallQ * smallP; //total price for small packages
    let largeTotalPrice = largeQ * price; //total price for large packages
    const orderPrice = smallTotalPrice + largeTotalPrice; //total price of this order
    return {
        products: [
    ...basketState.products, //--> **THIS IS NOT WORKING**
            {
                id: id,
                name: name,
                smallQ: smallQ,
                smallTotalP: smallTotalPrice,
                largeQ: largeQ,
                largeTotalP: largeTotalPrice,
                orderPrice: orderPrice,
            },
        ],
        totalPrice: basketState.totalPrice + orderPrice,
    };
}
//Default action
return basketState;
};
```

When I hover over `...basketState.products` I've got an error saying:

**Type** '[{ id: number | undefined; name: string; smallQ: number; smallTotalP: number; largeQ: number; largeTotalP: number; orderPrice: number; }, { id: number | undefined; name: string; smallQ: number; smallTotalP: number; largeQ: number; largeTotalP: number; orderPrice: number; }]' **is not assignable to type** '[{ id: number | undefined; name: string; smallQ: number; smallTotalP: number; largeQ: number; largeTotalP: number; orderPrice: number; }]'.

**Source has 2 element(s) but target allows only 1.ts(2322)**

BasketContext.tsx(8, 2): **The expected type comes from property 'products' which is declared here on type 'IBasketState'**

Is the problem the fact that in my interface I have declared only one object in products array and I'm trying to have 2 now? If so how can I bypass that?

Comment: Does this help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64308563/source-has-x-elements-but-target-allows-only-1/64308581 ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your guess is correct: the `products` property is typed as a tuple containing exactly one element.

What you could try is to turn it into an array of products:

```
interface BasketState {
    products: Product[];
    totalPrice: number;
}

interface Product {
    id: number | undefined;
    name: string;
    smallQ: number;
    smallTotalP: number;
    largeQ: number;
    largeTotalP: number;
    orderPrice: number;
}
```

You can read more on the tuple types in TypeScript here: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#tuple-types

Answer (score 4):

You have declared `products` as a tuple with a single object (`[T]`), instead of a list (`T[]` or `Array<T>`). So in other words, what you want is:

```
export interface IBasketState {
products: Array<{
        id: number | undefined;
        name: string;
        smallQ: number; //small packages quantity
        smallTotalP: number; //price for all small packages
        largeQ: number; //large packages quantity
        largeTotalP: number; //price for all large packages
        orderPrice: number; //total price of this order
    }>;
    totalPrice: number;
}
```

Sometimes, it can be nicer to define the type of the item instead of the list, so that your interface can look like this:

```
export interface IProduct = {
    id: number | undefined;
    name: string;
    smallQ: number; //small packages quantity
    smallTotalP: number; //price for all small packages
    largeQ: number; //large packages quantity
    largeTotalP: number; //price for all large packages
    orderPrice: number; //total price of this order
}

export interface IBasketState {
    products: IProduct[];
    totalPrice: number;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I'm just learning TypeScript and this helped me understeand the issue.